# Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add an objective C [library for toasts](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast) to my xcode project.
But I'm getting a number of these errors:

`"Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView'"`

`"Expected a type"`

I have linked with the QuartzCore.framework. And the .m file has been added to compile sources.
What am I missing? I'm a newbie to ios. Please help.

Comment: Please paste more code...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is a bug in the library.  The header file ([`UIView+Toast.h`](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast/blob/master/Toast/Toast/UIView%2BToast.h)) uses `UIView` but doesn't import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`, so copying its source files into your project can give you this error.

(**UPDATE**: [This bug was fixed on October 14, 2014.](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast/commit/0472e372fb3d9bc4817e253096f1a7f036999920#diff-bb1f487794b73b8383c530091026687b))

One way to fix this is to add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to the top of `UIView+Toast.h`.

Another way is to add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to your target's `.pch` file in the “Supporting Files” group, if your project has a `.pch` file.  It looks like Xcode 6's project templates don't include a `.pch` file, so you might not be able to use this fix easily.

Comment: Right Answer, i have just added #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
 in .pch file. everything work fine.

Comment: Two thumbs up! I have a hybrid class where the swift class is trying to get an Objective class through a bridge header. I get this error and thousands more (for as many UIView as I declared i.e UILabel, UITextView etc). Surely enough the objective C class didn't import UIKit. Adding that fixed it.  The question is: the Objective C class worked fine without importing that UIkit package; why?

Comment: Perhaps the project has a `.pch` (precompiled header) that imports UIKit.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include UIKit, which is where `UIView` is defined: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`