# I am surprised after getting this great error "Cannot Find interface declaration for NSHttpCookie"

Tags: objective-c, json, ios6.1, nshttpcookie

I am new on IOS. I am going to use JSON web services. In my NSHttpCookieAddition class , I found this error. What will be the solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26306189/2629258

Comment: yes i have checked it.  When iam trying to add UIKit framework than i found that there is not available UIKIt framework in link libraries.